# Action script3 save movie clips state between scenes

Tags: actionscript-3, local-shared-object

I have a problem here,  I cannot save movie clips state within scenes especially when I use "gotoAndPlay" to go between them..
I tried to search a lot but none. I am using Action script 3

The codes that I tried but I got error from:

```
    *var so: SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savedg")
    var xpos = so.data.xpos
    var ypos = so.data.ypos
    gotoAndPlay(so.data.ypos)
    so.flush()*
```

The error I get is that:
" argument error # 2109: Frame label not found in scene null" 
Although I have my scenes labeled

Please, I need your help so necessarily.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe your so.data.ypos is null ? Try to trace("My Y: " + so.data.ypos); and see if you will get any output for the ypos value. And maybe you need to cast the value to an integer: gotoAndPlay(int(so.data.ypos))

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I will let u know as soon as I try it. Thanks again